# How to pick offensive words from a sentence or mixedmatch sentence with offensive words

Tags: javascript

I want to avoid offensive words from the area where user create the content (Social Platform like where user is write something for Post on platform)

For that I have an approach where I have An array where all offensive words will be store.

Now for checking that sentence contain any offensive words I Wrote the Approach i.e

```
//NOTE: This array has offensive words. But I have not written here for not spreading any vulgarity to this platform.
const offensiveHolder = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5"];
    if (offensiveHolder.indexOf(req.body.word) > -1) {
      console.log("Username has exist offensive word");
    } else {
      console.log("Username has not exist offensive word");
    }
```

This is a very basic script which can identify if words exactly wrote like this...

Suppose I wrote H1TEST1KL, so here If I remove H1 from start and KL from end then this word is offensive.

My script will fail because it doesn't have enough logic to identify..
Is Someone have any approach by which I can get a clue to write the logic which can perform my desired task...

And I hope this algorithm will solve many people who build some platform for user interaction and don't want any dirty words which can spoil the user interactions.

Really appreciate for one who suggest/help me for this

Comment: @CertainPerformance this is not his problem, the problem is to find if a word like 'EX1' is , but the input can be H1EX1H1
So he need to check the whole word and substring them for get if there is a match in the offensiveHolder

Comment: @ntzz Exactly dear, that is my concern.

Comment: As much as I hate to suggest it, this sounds like the sort of situation where Regex is the way to go. Checking that your banned word is wrapped with either whitespace, punctuation or the start/end of the string.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I read the question to mean that the asker wanted to match only full words (e.g. Match "ass" but not "bass") rather than find offensive substrings, perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: @DBS I took his *`H1TEST1KL` -> TEST1 is included, therefore offensive* to mean that bad words included in other words should be detected?

Comment: @CertainPerformance You're right, I misunderstood the question, but I would urge Abhay not to censor sub-strings if they can avoid it, false positives can be surprisingly common with this sort of thing (And anyone trying to get around censorship will manage it anyway)

Comment: As well as not censoring sub-strings, for people who live in Scunthorpe (for example - there are many, many more), I'd also recommend replacing the swears, rather than simply removing them, or you'll get people (like me) who circumvent it very easily by posting things like `TESTEST1T1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the basic problem of the code in your question, you need to go the other way around - rather than checking whether the input string exactly matches one of the strings in the `offensiveHolder` array (which will be pretty unlikely), check whether `.some` of the strings in `offensiveHolder` are included in the input string. Also make sure to convert all strings to lower case before comparison:

```js
const offensiveHolder = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"];
function hasBadWord(input) {
  const lowerInput = input.toLowerCase();
  return offensiveHolder.some(badword => lowerInput.includes(badword));
};
console.log(hasBadWord('fooTEST1bar'));
console.log(hasBadWord('footest999bar'));
console.log(hasBadWord('H1TEST1KL'));
```

Comment: not eaxtly, according to question.. H1TEST1KL should be offensive.

Comment: It is indeed detected as offensive, I edited it in as another test case? Is there a problem with it?

Comment: It Works exactly... Lemme  use and if anymore things arises then I will Comment or discuss here. Really Appreciare @CertainPerformance for your support. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Simple without arrow functionality,

```js
var offensiveWords = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"];


function hasBadWord(input){
return offensiveWords.some(function(offesnsiveWord) {
    return input.toLowerCase().includes(offesnsiveWord);
});
}

console.log(hasBadWord('H1TEST1KL'));
console.log(hasBadWord('H1TES91KL'));
```